# Convert string to DateTime inside Filter/ Where/Find query - MongoDB .NET Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a booking mogoDb collection,

```
public string CreationDate { get; set; }
// removed rest
```

I try to retrieve the list of booked hotels between 2 dates.

```
            startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Start + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // this works

            endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(End + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  // this works

            var filter = Builders<HotelBookingDocument>.Filter.Gt(s => (DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), startDate);

            filter &= Builders<HotelBookingDocument>.Filter.Lt(s => (DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), endDate);

            return await HotelBookingCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();  // this does not work
```

inside `Where` also does not works, give same error

```
   query = await HotelBookingCollection.AsQueryable().Where(s => (
                          DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= endDate)
                    ).ToListAsync();
```

inside `Find`

```
query = await HotelBookingCollection.Find(s => (
                         startDate <= DateTime.ParseExact(s.CreationDate + " " + "00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    ).ToListAsync();
```

all give same errors

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
Unable to determine the serialization information for s => ParseExact(((s.CreationDate + " ") + "00:00:00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Why isn't `CreationDate` a `DateTime` / Mongo `IsoDate`?

Comment: CreationDate stored as String. I can't change to Date time in DB. I was cached from another DB

Comment: I'd guess then that you might need to write some code to use `Filter.Where` ([docs for $where](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)). It won't be an efficient query though.

Comment: I've edited the question, I tried with `where` and `find` too. But I got same error

Comment: No, that's `.AsQueryable().Where`. That's a LINQ query that gets converted into a normal filter query. `Builders<HotelBookingDocument>.Filter.Where` gets translated into a Mongo `$where` query. It's a different thing entirely. `$where` is basically running a JavaScript function you define on each record to determine if it should be returned.

Comment: I tried `Fliter.Where` also. I faced same error. 
`System.InvalidOperationException: ParseExact((({document}{CreationDate} + " ") + "00:00:00"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", ) is not supported.`

Comment: Did you write an appropriate _JavaScript_ (not C#!) query in the `$where`?

Comment: I stopped fighting with DateTime in any database in general, now I use integer and convert Date or Date+Time into a long. You also need to define your timezone reference. DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
You can sort, find, create test query by hand ... very convenient, only need some easy convert code.